# Why were those "not constructive" comment flags declined?

Tags: discussion, comments, flagging

[Comment 1](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/83295/should-you-always-minimize-cognitive-load#comment131440_83295)
[Comment 2](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/83295/should-you-always-minimize-cognitive-load#comment131506_83295)
[Comment 3](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/83295/should-you-always-minimize-cognitive-load/83364#comment131623_83364)

What all of those comments basically say is: "this is a useful question/answer". However there is already a way to show whether a post is useful; votes.

The meaning of those comments is actually identical to "+1 great post" which, [as mentioned here](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1568/71442), is useless.

Why were those flags declined?